# using component or use separate controller

Tags: angularjs

Following Angular 1.5 tutorial, they had the `controller` wrapped in `component()` like this

```
angular.
module('myList').
component('myList', {
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: ['MyList',
    function MyController($scope){
      var self = this;
      $scope.get({
        id : '0'
      }).then(function(response){
        return self.contents;
      })
    }
  ]
});
```

In order to prepare migrating to `Angular2`, what is the best practice in terms of placing the `controller` in its own `js` file?  
Should I follow this example or should I separate this code into 2 files because of concern?

note: I just realized the `component()` class came out last year on `1.5` and i've been mislead by tutorials prior to this release.

Comment: you can use them like constructor function & create instances in your respective classes/component.

Comment: @user32 are you saying to create functions inside a `controller` file and call them from my `component`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to keep your entities in different files even `module` items registration. Let me explain on the simple example:

Let's imagine you have some bigger module with UI stuff `module('uiStuff')`. So I suggest such structure:

uiStuff (folder)

- uiStuff.module.js
- uiStuff.service.js

  myList (folder)

  - myList.component.js
  - myList.controller.js
  - myList.partial.html

Your module files will always include just registering angular entities - services, components, directives etc. In the future, it gives you some advantages because there is no need in this code in the Angular2 and you will able to get rid of these files easily.

Example **uiStuff.module.js** :

```
angular.module('uiStuff')
  .service('someService', SomeService)
  .component('myList', myListComponent);
```

Where `SomeService` - some function constructor, and `myListComponent` is Component object. Let's see below **myList.component.js**:

```
var myListComponent = {
    bindings: {
       variable:'<'
    },
    templateUrl: 'myList.partial.html',
    controller: MyController
    // and all other component settings
}
```

And in the same way controllers and HTML templates, just separate files. Of course in my opinion, with migration in mind, it is better to switch to TypeScript language it will simplify a lot of things for you.

**CONCLUSION:**
But anyway my point is general for both es5, es6 and TypeScript AngularJs migration strategies:

1. keep entities in different files (controllers, components, services etc.)
2. keep module registering in separate file (uiStuff.module.js in example)
3. try to follow Angular2 naming convention (`name.service.js`, `name.component.js` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I was suggesting that:
/* in mylist.controller.js */

```
   function MyController($scope){
     //your code
    }
```

Now in my view/Component,

```
declare var MyController:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-elem',
    templateUrl: 'test.html'
})

export class MyComponent {  
  new MyController(this)
}
```

there are some suggestions on here,http://blog.rangle.io/upgrade-your-application-to-angular-2-with-ng-upgrade/

Comment: It's just a thought.

Comment: There's no reason for weird thing like `export class MyComponent {  
  new MyController(this)
}`. Component class *is* controller class. And `$scope` can't be just substituted with `this`.

Comment: what i am trying to do is pass context of class to controller. any work around?

Comment: Why? `MyController` should just become `MyComponent`. The class should be refactored to use `this` instead of `$scope` for scope properties, it is a good practice for A1 components. There's no way to get rid of `$scope` for scope events and watchers, this will be a subject for refactoring for A1 to A2 migration.

Comment: right. It's better to move controller code to component.